# The error results lead by mixing or/and in Python

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I am using bisection method to find a number. The first part of my code is:

```
    print("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")
        low = 0
        high = 100
        guess = int(0.5*(low + high))
        print("Is your secret number", guess,"?")
        ans = input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate 
    the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.")
        while ans != 'h' or ans != 'l' or ans != 'c':
            print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
            print("Is your secret number", guess,"?")
            print(ans)
            ans = input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to 
indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.")
```

When I execute the code, no matter what I put in keyboard, then WHILE loop keeps returning: "Sorry, I did not understand your input." then ask me to input again.

Could anyone let me know why this happens?

Thank you!

Comment: You should use `and` instead of `or` in while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets suppose you typed h

```
h!=h (False)
h!=l(True)
h!=c(True)
```

False or True or True = True so it will continue

What you need to do is change the "or's" on your code to and's. Doing this , if one of them is False then the whole expression will be False then it wont run the loop again :)

Answer (score 0):

`while ans != 'h' or ans != 'l' or ans != 'c':` should be `while ans != 'h' and ans != 'l' and ans != 'c':`

Comment: Explaining **why** is more important to a beginner than fixing their code.

Comment: Oh, I suddenly understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ch=chr
    low = 0
    high = 100

    guess = (low+high)/2
print('Please think of a number between 0 and 100! ')    
    while ch != 'c':
        print("is your secret number  ",round(guess))
        ch=input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high 'l' to indicate guess is too low and 'c' for correct: ")


        if ch=='l':
            low = guess
        elif ch=='h':
            high = guess
        elif ch=='c':
            break;
        elif (ch!='c' or ch!='l' or ch!='h' ):
            print('I did not understand what you entered')

        guess = (low+high)/2
    print('Game over. Your secret number was: ',round(guess))
```

Comment: when 1st guess 50 will apear I will see if  50 is too high its mean 50 is greater than guess then high=guess=50 means guess lies 1-50 ,and if 50 is too low its mean guess is greater than 50 and low=guess=50 means guess lies 50-100